# Parsing error - Android java

Tags: java, android, parsing, gridview

I'm trying to fill a gridview dynamically with icons. I Followed the gridview hello tutorial. However the array with the images is not always exactly the same. Depending on the action before, a different `image array` is given (extracted from soap response), which is constituted of the icon names, e.g. agenda => agenda.png. I wanted to create the array by looping through the array and adding it with `R.drawable + icon_name`. However `R.drawable` is not able to parse to the requested Integer array.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
    private Context mContext;
    final ArrayList<String> image = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("image");

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return icoontjes.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> icoontjes;
    {
        for (int i=0; i<image.size(); i++){
            Integer icon= Integer.valueOf("R.drawable."+image.get(i));
            icoontjes.add(icon);
        }
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(icoontjes.get(position));
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
for (int i=0; i < image.size(); i++) {
    Integer icon = getResources().getIdentifier(image.get(i), "drawable", "your.package");
    icoontjes.add(icon);
}
```

where `your.package` is the base package of your android application (the package in which you have your `static final R class` defined.

This way the `icon` variable will hold the id of your drawable based on your `image.get(i)`.

Answer (score 1):

i can give u an answer but you shouldn't (really shouldn't) do this ...

instead of

```
Integer icon= Integer.valueOf("R.drawable."+image.get(i));
```

try

```
R.class.getField("R.drawable."+image.get(i)).getInt(null)
```